# Arrow function into "ordinary" function expression in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, react-component

I want to change the arrow style function **(at onChange)** in this react component into an ordinary function. I'm a beginner and for me it is helpful to see both versions side by side since I have a hard time getting the hang for the new arrow function syntax.

It should be possible but how would the could below look like using "ordinary" functions?

```
import React from "react";

function Input1(props) {
  //console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={event => props.handleChange("email", event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Input1;
```

Comment: `function (event) { return props.handleChange("email", event.target.value); }` ?

Comment: If you just want a multi-line function, just using `event => { /* multi-line of code here */ }` would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import React from "react";

function Input1(props) {
  //console.log(props)

  function onChange(event) {
    props.handleChange("email", event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Input1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
  <input
    onChange={function(event) {
          props.handleChange("email", event.target.value)
         }
   }
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";

function Input1(props) {

  function changeHandler(event) {
     props.handleChange("email", event.target.value)
  }

  //console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={changeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Input1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from "react";

class Input1 extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //need to bind in case of using function decleration
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

 handleChange(event){
   props.handleChange("email", event.target.value);
  }

 render() {
   return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    </div>
   )
 }
```

}